# probability of number of comparisons of randomized quicksort

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, computer-science, sorting

> Let's assume we have an array of length $5$ which contains pairwise different integers. The subcript denotes the order of the respective integer, so $i_1<i_2<i_3<i_4<i_5$.
>
> We apply the randomized quicksort algorithm to the unordered array and would like to know the probability $P(A_{24})$ that two integers $s_2$ and $s_4$ are being compared. (Note that every item in the array is chosen as pivot with equal probability)

---

In our lecture the professor simply says that if we think about it for a while it becomes trivial that $P(A_{24})=\frac{2}{4-2+1}=\frac{2}{3}$. However it didn't....

---

I would like to have a mathematical frame to argue that $P(A_{24})=\frac{2}{3}$.

**My attempt:**

So far I have only assumed that we already have a discrete probability space $(\Omega,P)$ where $\Omega=\{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4,i_5\}$ and $B_i$ denotes the event that $s_i$ has been chosen as pivot element. So I simply collect all the events where $s_2$ or $s_4$ are the pivot at some stage during the algorithm and get
\begin{align*}
&P(A_{24})=\\
&P(B_2)+P(B_4)+P(B_1)P(B_2\mid B_1)+P(B_5)P(B_2\mid B_5)+P(B_5)P(B_4\mid B_5)+P(B_1)P(B_4\mid B_1)\\
&+P(B_1)P(B_5\mid B_1)P(B_2\mid B_1\cap B_5)+P(B_5)P(B_1\mid B_5)P(B_2\mid B_5\cap B_1)\\
&+P(B_1)P(B_5\mid B_1)P(B_4\mid B_1\cap B_5)+P(B_5)P(B_1\mid B_5)P(B_4\mid B_5\cap B_1)\dots
\end{align*}
If we use some intuition and the fact that every element has the same probability to be chosen as pivot we get (conditional) probabilities
\begin{align*}
&\dots=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\\
&+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\\
&=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{15}=\frac{2}{3}.
\end{align*}

Though this seems much clearer to me why we get $\frac{2}{3}$ I am not sure about the actual definition of the probability space. How would you set up an appropriate probability space in order to derive $P(A_{24})$? Or is there a simpler approach to show why $P(A_{24})=\frac{2}{3}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between $i_2$ and $i_4$ there is only one number, $i_3$. If it is chosen as a pivot before $i_2$ or $i_4$ are, then $i_2$ and $i_4$ won't be compared with each other (they will be compared with $i_3$ and placed on the opposite sides of the pivot).  So the probability of $i_2$  and $i_4$ not being compared is the probability of $i_3$ being chosen as pivot first out of the set $\{i_2, i_3, i_4\}$, which is $\frac{1}{3}$. By complement, the probability of them being compared is $\frac{2}{3}$.

---

Edit: here is a more formal version of the argument:

Let $T= \{i_1, i_2 \dots i_5\}$, $\;S=\{i_2,i_3,i_4\}$.

Let $p_1$ be the first pivot chosen.

Denote $P_T(A_{24})$ to be the probability that the comparison $A_{24}$ occurs in the quicksort of a random ordering of $T$. Ie. we consider the quicksort of a random ordering of $T$ as an implicit condition for our events to happen at all.

We will take an inductive approach to the general formula. We know that $P_S(A_{24}) = \frac{2}{3}$ (quicksort of a random ordering of $S$). Additionally, assume we proved $P_M(A_{24}) = \frac{2}{3}$ for any $M$ which has $S\subset M$ and $|M| < |T|$.

We have:

$$P_T(A_{24}) =  P_T(p_1  \in  S) \; P_T( A_{24} \;|\; p_1  \in  S ) +  P_T(p_1   \notin   S) \;P_T( A_{24} \;|\; p_1   \notin   S) $$

Let us compute the terms of this formula.

$P_T(p_1  \in  S) = \frac{3}{5}$

$P_T(p_1  \notin     S) = (1 - P_T(p_1  \in  S)) = \frac{2}{5}$

These only important thing about the above branch condition probabilities is that they always sum to 1. Our main aim is to show that:
$$ P_T( A_{24}  \;|\; p_1  \in  S ) =  P_T( A_{24} \;|\; p_1   \notin   S) = \frac{2}{3}$$

If we show that these two are equal, the branch conditions $P_T(p_1  \in  S)$  and $P_T(p_1  \notin  S)$  sum up by common factor.

From the initial argument we can see that  $P_T( A_{24} \;|\; p_1  \in  S ) = \frac{2}{3}$. (the first pivot being in $\{i_2,i_3,i_4\}$ makes it easy to compute). What remains is to show that $P_T( A_{24} \;|\; p_1  \notin  S ) = \frac{2}{3}$ .

We have:

$$P_T( A_{24} \;|\; p_1  \notin  S ) =\\ P_T(p_1 < i_2 \;|\;  p_1  \notin  S )  \;P_T( A_{24} \;|\;  p_1< i_2 ) + \\+\;P_T( i_4 < p1 \;|\; p_1  \notin  S ) \;P_T( A_{24} \;|\;  i_4 < p_1 )$$

As before,  $P_T( p_1 < i_2 \;|\;   p_1  \notin  S)$ and $P_T(i_4 < p1 \;|\;  p_1  \notin  S)$ are complementary events that sum to 1, we are only interested in the other factors.

$$P_T(A_{24}\;|\; p_1<i_2) = \sum_{j < i_2} P_T( p_1 = j\;|\; p_1 < i_2 ) P_T( A_{24} \;|\; p_1 = j)$$

Same argument, $P_T( p_1 = j\;|\; p_1 < i_2 )$ sum to 1, we are interested in  $P_T( A_{24}\;|\; p_1 = j)$. Given $j < i_2$ we have:

$$P_T( A_{24} \;|\; p_1 = j) = P_{\{x\in T \;|\; x > j\}}(A_{24})$$

Ie. if the first pivot is chosen such that $S$ will fall on the right side of the pivot, what remains is the probability of $A_{24}$ appearing in a quicksort of said right side.
However, the set $ L = \{x\in T | x > j\} $  obeys $S \subset L$ and $|L| < |T|$ . Therefore, by inductive hypothesis we have $P_{\{x\in T | x > j\}}(A_{24}) = \frac{2}{3}$ for $j< i_{2}$. We can do a similar thing for $$P_T( A_{24} \;|\; p_1 = k) = P_{\{x\in T \;|\; x < k\}}(A_{24})$$
where $k > i_4$ .

These correspond to the cases where all elements of $S$ fall on the right or the left side of the first pivot, respectively. They all reduce to $\frac{2}{3}$, except for the branch condition probabilities, which always sum to one. So the final probability is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Why not out of the set $\{i_1,i_2, i_3, i_4\}$? Your answer seems very intuitive but is it possible to put it into a probability space context?

Comment: What matters is the order of choosing of the pivots, specifically, only those pivots between, and including, $i_2$ and $i_4$. Because only if an "in-between" pivot (in our case, only $i_3$), is chosen first (ie. before the other two), will those two be separated and never be compared. The "in between" pivots act as "walls" between $i_2$ and $i_4$, if chosen first. The other ones (such as  $i_1$) do not.

Comment: It is clear to what happens if the pivot lies between/is equal to $s_2$ or$s_4$  but I don't understand how this allows us to derive a probability.

Comment: I've tried to formalize the argument.

Comment: Excellent answer! But it feels a bit like "cheating" because we don't know if there exists a probability space that suits - we simply assume that it already exists without knowing how it looks like. Do you think that there is an easy way at all to find a discrete probability space? I am thinking of something like $\Omega:=\Omega_1\times\times\dots\Omega_n$ where the different $\Omega_i$ denote the selection of a pivot. Then we define a probability function on each $\Omega_i$. As it is not clear beforehand how many pivots we will select it seems complicated to find an appropriate sample space.

Comment: To "prove" a probability space exists you could simply program a random quicksort algorithm (with recording of what comparisons take place when running it) and run it for a couple of times to estimate the probabilities of said comparisons occurring. 

In my approach a "probability triple" would be defined for the quicksort of any random set $M$. The events would be of the type "the first pivot being a given element", and "a comparison (eventually) occurring between two given elements".

Comment: The proof is an inductive/recursive argument over those sets $M$ (and the associated probability measures) which include $S$ and do not include any element outside of $S$ which is greater than $i_2$ and smaller than $i_4$. 
  
So, to prove and compute the probability/event structure of the quick sorting of a given set $M$, you do it with recursive relationships to the probability/event-structures of the quick-sorting over smaller subsets of $M$.